# Oledb Update command

Tags: c#, oledb

I make a program that saves and update a data from the database, I can save and read data, I can also update but the problem is, I can't select the `"ID"` as the index, here is my sample code using `"ID"` as the index,

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Records SET FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, Age = @age, Address = @address, Course = @course WHERE [ID] = @id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(label7.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Connection = cn;
cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
    cn.Close();
}
```

and here is my update code that works, but the index is the `"firstname"`,

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Records SET FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, Age = @age, Address = @address, Course = @course WHERE FirstName = @firstname";
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(label7.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Connection = cn;
cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
    cn.Close();`
}
```

It works but the problem is I can't update the `"FirstName"`, Is there a way that I can also update the Firstname? or use the `"ID"` as the index? thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what database you are going against, however, I don't know if the OleDB is being picky on the ordinal sequence of your parameters.  ie: Have you tried putting your "ID" parameter in the last position to match the actual order of the fields of your update command?  I don't know if it's throwing it out.

Comment: But in the delete command, I can successfully delete using the `"ID"`,  I got no error in updating but its not updating,

Comment: Yes, You're right, It's throwing the value of the first parameter, and I put the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", label7.Text);` in the last line, it's now working perfectly, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You should add the following code after the last line of `ID`:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Records SET FirstName = @firstname, LastName = @lastname, Age = @age, Address = @address, Course = @course WHERE [ID] = @id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(label7.Text));
cmd.Connection = cn;
cn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); {
    MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
    cn.Close();
}
```