# Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, ms-access

What is wrong with this code? I did everything but I still get

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement

Please help. Thank you in advance.

```
OleDbConnection conn = default(OleDbConnection);

OleDbCommand cmd = default(OleDbCommand);

conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=DemoDB.accdb");

string sql = "UPDATE APPOINTMENTS Set ([CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + ", [DateTime]= " + dateTimePicker5.Text + ", [Time]=" + txtNewTime.Text + " WHERE [CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + ");";

conn.Open();

cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//execute the sql command

MessageBox.Show("Appointment Changed Successful");

//close the connectionstring
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Use Parameters and you will be free from this problem (and others as well)

Comment: I am not good using Parameters would you help to do so, please.

Comment: This link shows examples of using parameters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126427/oledb-update-command

Comment: Also you need to use `dateTimePicker5.Value` instead of it's `Text` property. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use a parameterized query instead for what you are currently using. this will solve the problem and also help you to prevent SQL Injection:

Here is an example:

```
string sql = "UPDATE APPOINTMENTS Set [CustomerID]=@id,[DateTime]=@dateTime,[Time]=@time WHERE [CustomerID]=@customerid";
using (OleDbConnection  cn = new OleDbConnection("Your connection string here"))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,cn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType .VarChar, 50).Value = "Some value Here";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateTime", OleDbType.Date).Value = "Some value Here";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@time", OleDbType.DBTime, 50).Value = "Some value Here";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@customerid", OleDbType .VarChar, 50).Value = "Some value Here";
                //execute command here
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mean `OleDbType` instead of `SqlDbType` I think :)

Comment: @SonerGönül : Brilliant Spot, thanks for the suggestion. i have updated the answer

Comment: i am using OLEDBtype not sqltype and i have some data there. i cannot transfer to the sqldbtype.

Comment: @AbdalaBernardo: Look at the updates; i have changed them to `OleDb.. `

Comment: Error 3 Cannot assign to 'cmd' because it is a 'using variable' C:\Users\Abdala\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ @un-lucky

Answer (score 0):

As a minimum, you must use the correct string expressions for date and time:

```
string sql = "UPDATE APPOINTMENTS Set ([CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + ", [DateTime]= #" + dateTimePicker5.Text + "#, [Time]=#" + txtNewTime.Text + "# WHERE [CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + ");";
```

And it can be reduced to:

```
string sql = "UPDATE APPOINTMENTS Set ([DateTime]= #" + dateTimePicker5.Text + "#, [Time]=#" + txtNewTime.Text + "# WHERE [CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + ");";
```

This, however, requires that your date and time *Text* are of the correct format. If not, you will have to first parse these to *DateTime*, then use *Format* or *ToString* to create the text to concatenate.

Or use parameters.

Answer (score -1):

change update query
use this

```
string sql = "UPDATE APPOINTMENTS Set [CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + ", [DateTime]= " + dateTimePicker5.Text + ", [Time]=" + txtNewTime.Text + " WHERE [CustomerID]=" + txtCid.Text + " ";
```

Also check your datatype of DateTime column

Comment: But of course, we don't recommend string concatenations on sql queries, right? We suggest them to use prepared statements.