# Can't update MS Access database in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, ms-access

My code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE student_info SET fee_due = @fee_due WHERE adm_no = @adm_no", con);

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adm_no", adm_no);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fee_due", fee_due);

int affect = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show(affect.ToString());
```

My code always shows 0 row affected every time but in my database the are must be a row that will be affect

Can you suggest me how I debug this problem?

Comment: Try to set the parameters in the correct order of your statement. OleDB is really picky when it gets to parameters. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126427/oledb-update-command and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648602/oledb-update-command-not-changing-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OleDB for MS Access **doesn't support** named parameters (only positional parameters), you must be very careful about providing the values in the same order in which you define the parameters.

In your case, the statement lists `@fee_due` first, before `@adm_no` - but you provide the values in the other order.

Change your code like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE student_info SET fee_due = @fee_due WHERE adm_no = @adm_no", con);

// provide the value for @fee_due FIRST    
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fee_due", fee_due);

// provide the value for @adm_no only after @fee_due
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adm_no", adm_no);

int affect = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show(affect.ToString());
```